# hide html5 video controls with css?

Tags: jquery, css, html, html5-video

I have a html5 video section as below and I want to hide the controls. I have made the video div clickable to show a 'modal' layer which plays the video in a larger size. I have done the coding to open the 'modal' and play the video OK. Is there a way to hide the controls with css, so I can make them visible again for responsive design?

```
<video id="sampleMovie2" controls>
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: by ommiting controls tag you can hide video controls. this is fairly trivial with javascript but don't really know about css-only solution except putting to video elements with same source in markup, one with controls attr and one without and toggle their visibility in media queries

Answer (score 1):

If you created your controls with HTML elements and bound your controls to the `video` using JS than yes, using CSS you could target the desired `device media` width and hide those elements.

Otherwise no.
But using JS you can toggle the `controls` property depending on the window width:

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/cecexavuma/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***

```
var $vid = $("#sampleMovie2");

function showControlsAt600() {
    $vid.prop( "controls", $(window).width() >= 600 );
}


showControlsAt600();
$(window).on("resize", showControlsAt600);
```

Comment: tks i will give it a try

Comment: @user3745738 you don't have to *try*. It already works ;) Simply copy-paste and edit eventually the `600` to whatever value you need.